# Most efficient database design for this data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, voting

My database knowledge is reasonable I would say, im using MySQL (InnoDb) for this and have done some Postgres work as well. Anyway...

- I have a large amount of Yes or No questions.
- A large amount of people can contribute to the same poll.
- A user can choose either option and this will be recorded in the database.
- User can change their mind later and swap choices which will require an update to the data stored.

My current plan for storing this data:

- POLLID, USERID, DECISION, TIMESTAMP

Obviously user data is in another table.

To add their choice, I would have to query to see if they have voted before and insert, otherwise, update.
If I want to see the poll results I would need to go iterate through all decisions (albeit indexed portions) every time someone wants to see the poll.

My questions are

1. Is there any more efficient way to store/query this?
2. Would I have an index on POLLID, or POLLID & USERID (maybe just a unique constraint)? Or other?
3. Additional side question: Why dont I have an option to choose HASH vs BTREE indexes on my tables like i would in Postgres?

Comment: Why would you have to iterate trough all decisions to see poll results? What stops you from having a table that you update with poll information each time a vote is cast? It saves the resources required for iterating trough everything in order to obtain the data.

Comment: Be careful of N.B.'s suggestion, whilst it can work - it can lead to de-normalisation as your votes cast may not reflect the poll information. It's best to calculate this information using SQL, it's powerful enough.

Comment: Actually it's not the best to do that. Cast / update a vote - increment/decrement counter stored somewhere else. Saves you iterating and summing every time someone connects. If implemented correctly (and I really can't see how it can be implemented badly since it's trivial), it works as one would expect.

Comment: I thought of this but ignored it for the reason given by Zeritor. Plus how would you keep track of who voted for what unless you had my design in addition to a counter? This would mean id have redundant data (wouldnt be in a normal form) Plus i couldnt get dates of votes... right?

Comment: Yes the implementation is trivial, but it requires an extra action on every vote. What if one action passes but the other fails (connectiong issues, database load issues)? Your data no longer adds up correctly. SQL is designed to have you using it to fulfil your questions, you shouldn't take values then do your own processing.

Comment: So the question is about **performance** yet materialized views are frowned upon? Once user casts or changes their vote, who says you can't update the table that holds the votes sorted by user and then update a table holding poll stats? This is standard practice used when you want performance. But if you're SQL evangelist, then why chase the performance?

Comment: ^ Thanks for the 'materialized view' suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design sounds good, a few ideas:

A table for polls: poll id, question.

A table for choices: choice id, text.

A table to link polls to choices: poll id->choice ids.

A table for users: user details, user ids.

A votes table: (user id, poll id), choice id, time stamp. (brackets are a unique pair)

Inserting/updating for a single user will work fine, as you can just check if an entry exists for the user id and the poll id.

You can view the results much easier than iterating through by using COUNT.

```
e.g.: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE pollid = id AND decision = choiceid
```

That would tell you how many people voted for "choiceid" in the poll "pollid".

Late Edit:

This is a way of inserting if it doesn't exist and updating if it does:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE UserId='Uid' AND PollId = 'pollid')
    UPDATE TableName SET (set values here) WHERE UserId='Uid' AND PollId = 'pollid'
ELSE   
    INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (insert values here)
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like a good answer. I said iterate because i didnt know the inner workings of the count function. Any light on the last q?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about indexing and I've never used postgres.

Comment: It's possible to write `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements in such a way that they don't update any rows if not possible, but they don't **fail**.  So it's possible to check, say, based on if they succeed at the `INSERT`, but 'rows updated' by the statement is 0...  You don't need the poll/choice cross-ref table if choices are only used for one poll (not sure if relevant).  And _technically_ storing both `choice_id` and `poll_id` in the votes table is denormalization, but properly normalizing it would make queries somewhat complicated.

Comment: @X-Zero, is it really denormalization? It seems ok to me but I could be wrong. Could you explain further, I would be interested to know. I can't see any other way of storing all the votes.

Comment: It's because the relationship between polls and choices have already been stored elsewhere, so it's unnecessary/possibly corruptible information (wrong choice for poll).  The proper one would be to store (`user_id`, `choice_id`), then navigate through the relationship to check that the user hasn't voted for a particular poll.  However, selectively denormalizing in this fashion is _probably_ okay, especially if only the choice is provided as a host variable, and poll is resolved from relationship tables (means `UPDATE`s take a bit more, but queries are much easier).

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. As a table already exists linking what poll has what answers, then yes, storing "poll id" in the votes table is de-normalising. I did not see that.

Comment: Great info, this is what i was hoping for. X-zero, how would i do these nonfailing insert/updates? Do you mean setting up the unique constraints so the insert is rejected if it exists already?

Comment: @Z-Mehn, I have updated my main post with a possible idea. I've not actually tested it though.

Comment: Take a look at <http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html > for better way of "inserting if it doesn't exist and updating if it does"`INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;`